# A Priority Queue Implementing 3 Arrays of 5 Items In Java

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

I have 3 arrays of 5 items. Inputting an integer that is less than 99 will place it in the first array, inputting an integer from 101 to 199 will put it into the second and 201-299 will put it into the 3rd array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class priorityQueue {
    private int[][] queueArray;
}

public priorityQueue() //constructor
{
    queueArray = new int[3][5];
}

public void printQueue() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(queueArray));
}

public boolean isFull(int[] array){
    return (array.length-1 == 5);
}

public boolean enqueue(int item){
    //returns true or false if enqueue is not possible
    //try lower priority queue(s) if necessary


}
```

I have no idea how to implement a priority into how integers are inserted, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you saying that you can't use the `PriorityQueue<E>` that is already part of Java collections?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could use PriorityQueue<E> since I have a two dimensional array and not a single array. My question is: how do I insert into my arrays so that the first array only has integers from 0-99, the second array has integers from 101 to 199, and so on?

Comment: Why are you using a 2D array? Is this a requirement?

Comment: Yes that was the description of the task:
Use an array of 3 arrays of 5 items
Row 0 is highest priority
Each of the 3 arrays implements a queue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary implementation of the requirements, for what it's worth. Note that you can get your index into the first level of `queueArray` by using integer division on your `item` parameter like so: `int whichQueue = item / 100;`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PriorityQueue
{
    private int[][] queueArray;

    public PriorityQueue() // constructor
    {
        queueArray = new int[3][5];
    }

    public void printQueue()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(queueArray));
    }

    public boolean isFull(int[] array)
    {
        return findEmptySlot(array) < 0;
    }

    public boolean enqueue(int item)
    {
        if (item < 1 || item > 299) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("item must be between 1 and 299");
        }
        for (int i = item / 100; i < this.queueArray.length; i++) {
            if (enqueue(item, this.queueArray[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean enqueue(int item, int[] queue) {
        int emptySlot = findEmptySlot(queue);
        if (emptySlot >= 0) {
            queue[emptySlot] = item;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int findEmptySlot(int[] queue) {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++) {
            if (queue[i] == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't ask for the answer, I could've figured out the rest myself. I just wanted to know how to enqueue into a 2d dimensional array with the different priorities involved.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Using integer division you can get your index into queueArray like so: `int index = item / 100;`

Comment: But if I put in, let's say, 205 first, wouldn't that get placed into array [0][0]? I would need it to be placed into array[2][0].

Comment: That's what I'm saying: 205 / 100 = 2. That's your index into queueArray. Now you just have to determine your index into queueArray[2].

Comment: Oh! I see it now. I didn't see that you used int i in this.queueArray[i]. Thanks so much!